# Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load shared object '/software/R...', installing dplyr on LSF GNU/Linux server

Tags: r, dplyr, installation, package

I tried installing 'dplyr' on a Linux server using the following code in a script:

```
install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE, lib = 'output/software/r/package/installation/', 
                 repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com')
```

but after running it with 'Rscript code.R' I got a long message followed by:

```
 ** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

...

g++  -I/software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -DBOOST_NO_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_INTEGRAL_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_LONG_LONG -DRCPP_USING_UTF8_ERROR_STRING -I"/lustre/.../project/output/software/r/package/installation/Rcpp/include" -I"/software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/library/BH/include" -I"/software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/library/bindrcpp/include" -I"/software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/library/plogr/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c hybrid_offset.cpp -o hybrid_offset.o
...

g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o dplyr.so RcppExports.o address.o api.o arrange.o between.o bind.o combine_variables.o distinct.o encoding.o filter.o group_by.o group_indices.o hybrid.o hybrid_count.o hybrid_debug.o hybrid_in.o hybrid_minmax.o hybrid_nth.o hybrid_offset.o hybrid_simple.o hybrid_window.o init.o join.o join_exports.o mutate.o rlang-export.o select.o set.o slice.o summarise.o test.o utils.o window.o
installing to /lustre/.../project/output/software/r/package/installation/dplyr/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/library/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /software/R-3.4.0/lib/R/library/bindrcpp/libs/bindrcpp.so)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’
```

I tried installing 'dplyr' without the dependencies and it gives the same messages.

Comment: Maybe try this first `install.packages('bindrcpp', dependencies = TRUE, lib = 'output/software/r/package/installation/', 
                 repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com')`

Comment: ...-c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o bindrcpp.so RcppExports.o create.o plogr.o test.o
installing to /lustre/.../project/output/software/r/package/installation/bindrcpp/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (bindrcpp)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/Rtmp8smu8o/downloaded_packages’       so this seems to be OK.

Comment: Why not add '.libPaths('output/software/r/package/installation/')' in my ~/.Rprofile ? I had 
.libPaths('output/software/r/package/installation/') in my Rscript. Why would putting it in bash_profile make a difference. It's working now by the way. Mysterious to me.