# input$shinyTree does not get updated after new render

Tags: r, shiny, shinytree

In the `shiny` app below, I have a reset button, which, well, resets the `shinyTree`. I figured that the corresponding `input$tree` does **not** get updated after pressing the reset, i.e. `input$tree` still reflects the un-reset state. Try the app by moving some nodes and press the reset button and you will see that while the output gets reset the `verbatimTextOutput` still shows the old version.

Is that behavior intentional? How do I force `shinyTree` to update the `input$tree` whenever `output$tree` is changed? Would [#89](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree/pull/89/commits/d649579b1f11f85cee15a093f8d12c5650b9dc7d) solve my issue?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("reset", "reset"),
                shinyTree("tree", dragAndDrop=TRUE, sort = F, wholerow = T, unique = T),
                verbatimTextOutput("str"))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tree <- renderTree({
    input$reset
    list(
      root3 = "234",
      root1 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "")
      ),
      root2 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "")
      )
    )
  })

  output$str <- renderPrint({
    # shinyTrees will also be available as inputs so you can
    # monitor changes that occur to the tree as the user interacts
    # with it.
    str(input$tree)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

To clarify: I have read [R Shiny - Resetting shinyTree node selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555281/r-shiny-resetting-shinytree-node-selections) before posting this question and though related, it is not solving my problem, because I am not using `updateTree` in the first place and in my real use case things are way more complicated. Thus, the highlighted solution to use an additional `reactiveVal` won't work smoothly.

I really need a solution which assures that `input$tree` is up to date regardless whether the tree was updated through user interaction or through `R` code itself.

I have only a superficial understanding of shiny input widgets, but I guess that [#89](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree/pull/89/commits/d649579b1f11f85cee15a093f8d12c5650b9dc7d) could solve my issue as it will pass a new tree to `shiny`  whenever there is a `refresh`. I will try this one out.

Comment: I have read this article upfront and though related it is not solving my issue. I made that clear in the post. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: Ah, ok - you should have mentioned that in the first place. I posted an alternative solution - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following, you can force to reset `input$tree` via JS:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("reset", "reset"),
                shinyTree("tree", dragAndDrop=TRUE, sort = F, wholerow = T, unique = T),
                verbatimTextOutput("str"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('tree', null);")
  })

  output$tree <- renderTree({
    input$reset
    list(
      root3 = "234",
      root1 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "")
      ),
      root2 = list(
        SubListA = list(leaf1 = "", leaf2 = "")
      )
    )
  })

  output$str <- renderPrint({
    str(input$tree)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Nice idea. I just added the dependence on `input$tree` in the `renderTree` for completeenss, but otherwise works like a charm! +1

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference and as already assumed, [#89](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree/pull/89/commits/d649579b1f11f85cee15a093f8d12c5650b9dc7d) solves this issue.

```
devtools::install_github("shinyTree/shinyTree#89")
options(shinyTree.refresh = TRUE)
```

Reason behind is that the `shinyTree` author decided not to callback on refresh (or `setState` for all it matters) thus `input$tree` does not "know" that it was changed and returns the stale tree. The new PR allows to explicitly callback on refresh (by setting the option), which solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this solution in R 4.0.2:

```
devtools::install_github("shinyTree/shinyTree#89")
options(shinyTree.refresh = TRUE)
```

For me it caused a issue similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836154/error-in-dyn-loadfile-dllpath-dllpath-unable-to-load-shared-object), which I was only able to resolve after re-installing R.